# Add bar button in UINavigationbar

Tags: iphone, ipad, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, back-button

I am new to iPhone developer,

I want to add one more button next to the Back button on my navigation bar, i am using navigation controller so back button is already there on left side. and on extreme right side i have added one button using

`self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = ModeButton;`

but when i write,

`self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = NewButton;`

NewButton overrides my back button, i want to place my new button next to back button.

**Any help will be appreciated.**

Comment: i think the link [here](http://osmorphis.blogspot.in/2009/05/multiple-buttons-on-navigation-bar.html) can help you.

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UINavigationItem` has a property `leftItemsSupplementBackButton`, you can use it.

leftItemsSupplementBackButton
A Boolean value indicating whether the left items are displayed in addition to the back button.

```
@property BOOL leftItemsSupplementBackButton
```

Discussion
Normally, the presence of custom left bar button items causes the back button to be removed in favor of the custom items. Setting this property to YES causes the items in the leftBarButtonItems or leftBarButtonItem property to be displayed to the right of the back button—that is, they are displayed in addition to, and not instead of, the back button. When set to NO, the items in those properties are displayed instead of the back button. The default value of this property is NO.

From [UINavigationController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html).

```
UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButtonItem =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(logout)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButtonItem;
self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;
```

Comment: can you suggest some example, i am very new here.

Comment: If you set the boolean the back button will be there, and your new button will get displayed right to the back button. My answer is edited by including code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should a flexible space for it to not overlap other, maybe something like this should get you started.

```
    UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(Back:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *newButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"newButton" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(newButtonMethod:)];

    NSArray *navBarItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:back, flexibleSpace, newButton, nil];
```

**EDIT:**

```
NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];  
UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(Back:)];
[buttons addObject:back];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
[buttons addObject:flexibleSpace];
    UIBarButtonItem *newButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"newButton" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(newButtonMethod:)];
[buttons addObject:newButton];

UIToolbar* myToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 45)];
        [myToolbar setTintColor:[self.navigationController.navigationBar tintColor]];
 [myToolbar setItems:buttons animated:NO];

UIBarButtonItem *myButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myToolbar];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = myButton;
```

Comment: how to add this array to navigation bar?

Comment: I am getting `SIGABRT` incompatible pointer type from NSArray to UIBarButtonItem

Comment: lol, your and is good but answer which i have accepted is a short and standard. but i will up vote your ans.

Answer (score 0):

Create one custom view which will contain two buttons, then create bar button item as follows:

```
UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButtonItem =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:userCustomView];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButtonItem;
```

Edit:
Below code is just an example of how you create two buttons,

```
UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] init];
customView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40);

UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button1 setTitle:@"Add" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 40);

UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button2 setTitle:@"del" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button2.frame = CGRectMake(60, 0, 50, 40);
[customView  addSubview:button2];
[customView addSubview:button1];

UIBarButtonItem *barItem =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customView];


self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barItem;
```

Comment: can you suggest some example, i am very new here. i want to add button on left side not on right side

Comment: your code is right but the problem is, i do not want to add back button, it is already added in navigation bar i don't know his name.

Answer (score 0):

For achieving this, you will have to make a Custom `UIBarButtonItem`. Ans in that you will have to put both the buttons, BackButton (User Defined) and NewButton respectively like this:

```
UIView *viewForLeftBarButton = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 100, 35)];
[viewForLeftBarButton addSubview:BackButton];
[viewForLeftBarButton addSubview:NewButton];

UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButtonItem =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:viewForLeftBarButton];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButtonItem;
```

Comment: i am not creating back button it is auto created, so m getting error here, `[viewForLeftBarButton addSubview:BackButton];` it shows BackButton is unexpected identifier.